# Is there any way on SpringBoot to return a configuration bean when a resource is NOT present?

Tags: java, spring-boot, conditional-statements

I'm looking for the oposite of:

```
@ConditionalOnResource(resources = "${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}")
```

I want something like `@ConditionalOnMissingResource`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a shorter or even a clever option, but this worked for me.

Decorate your bean creation method with

```java
@Conditional(BuildInfoResourceNotAvailableCondition.class)
```

And add this static nested class to your configuration class:

```java
    static class BuildInfoResourceNotAvailableCondition extends SpringBootCondition {

        private final ResourceLoader defaultResourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

        @Override
        public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            ResourceLoader loader = context.getResourceLoader();
            loader = (loader != null) ? loader : this.defaultResourceLoader;
            Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
            String location = environment.getProperty("spring.info.build.location");
            if (location == null) {
                location = "classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties";
            }
            ConditionMessage.Builder message = ConditionMessage
                    .forCondition("BuildInfoResource");
            if (!loader.getResource(location).exists()) {
                return ConditionOutcome
                        .match(message.didNotFind("build info at").items(location));
            }
            return ConditionOutcome
                    .noMatch(message.found("build info at").items(location));
        }

    }
```